# grails spring security - implementing screen lock

Tags: grails, spring-security

After login into grails application with spring security  enabled, if we implement a screen lock feature with in the application, how to recheck the password entered by the user.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are saving encoded passwords to DB then
You need to do something like this

```
 def userInstance = ... //get user instance

 if (springSecurityService.encodePassword(params.pass) != userInstance.password) {
 ...
 }
```